# Why is Rails.logger nil in test environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

UPDATE: The following appears to be a result of the Rails environment not being loaded when `rake test` runs my unit tests (currently only a single module which lives in /lib). Is it possible to include the environment from the command line, instead of changing the rake task itself? Is there a better way to go about this (short of using dependency injection in order to introduce Rails.logger, which is what I'll probably end up doing)?

I'm seeing a `NoMethodError` in my test environment because of the following call to `Rails.logger.error`:

```
# /lib/square.rb

module Square

  def self.get_total_sales_for_location(location_id, timeout: 5)
    begin
      url = "https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations/#{location_id}/transactions"
      headers = {Authorization: "Bearer #{ENV['SQUARE_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN']}"}
      response = RestClient::Request.execute  headers: headers,
                                              method: :get,
                                              timeout: timeout,
                                              url: url

      if response.code == 200
        JSON.parse response.body
      else
        fail
      end
    rescue => error
      Rails.logger.error "Square::get_total_sales_for_location - #{error.message}"
      raise
    end
  end
end
```

This all works fine from the console, however running my tests results in: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'error' for nil:NilClass`

My *temporary* workaround is to use `:try` to prevent the exception, but that's very kludgy.

Comment: In your code sample you are using `Rails.logger.log` which won't work

Comment: Use Rails.logger.info or Rails.logger.debug

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. My code is actually using 'error' but that was lost in translation.

Comment: Do you actually load Rails in the context of this test? Because this file is stored in the lib folder, I would expect it to not be depending on Rails and there would not load Rails when testing...

Comment: That's a good point. I was under the assumption that the provided 'rake test' task would. I'll try to dig that up in the Rails source.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `rake environment test`. But I would guess it would be nicer to just make the test task dependent on the environment with `task test: :environment do`